# Is it possible to calculate the shear wave velocity in lab using ultrasonic test?

Tags: civil-engineering, vibration, ultrasound

I have an ultrasonic testing equipment that can only measure the direct and semi-direct ( (a) and (b) in the image below):

[image]

I can measure compression wave velocities fairly easily, but I would like to know if it is possible to measure the shear wave velocity.

Is it possible to measure the shear wave velocity in a lab setting using this? What should the distance between the two sensors be to provide accurate measurments?

Answer (score 1):

Well, nothing is impossible. But, lets see what you are trying to do:

[image: Diagram of waves]

This diagram is simplified; in reality, there are 3 different P (compression) waves and 2 different S (shear) waves.

Measurement of the first P wave is very easy because it depends on the first arrival time (it is the fastest wave).

But to measure the S wave, you first need to isolate the noise, the reflections caused by P waves, the refraction and then determine if you have the correct S wave or not.

Doing so is very hard.

However, you can use specific transducers called shear wave transducer that will generate shear waves directly so you can measure them.